# How to run two different technologies project using different ports on Apache using rewrite module

Tags: wordpress, apache, ubuntu, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a Wordpress website running on Lampp at 80 Port and a Java Spring Hibernate project running on Wildfly at 8080 port.
Is it possible that i can access both using http://localhost/wpproject and http://localhost/javaspringproject
using apache rewrite  / virtualhost etc ?

I want to put lampp apache at the front.

Currently i can access those like http://localhost/wpproject and http://localhost:8080/javaspringproject.

I am using Ubuntu Linux OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a reverse proxy, not a rewrite. Add this to your virtual host configuration:

```
ProxyPass /javaspringproject http://127.0.0.1:8080/javaspringproject
ProxyPassReverse /javaspringproject http://127.0.0.1:8080/javaspringproject
```

Make sure `mod_proxy` is enabled

Comment: Thank you very much. It has resolved my issue. Many Thanks.

Comment: Sir Please help me.
I have to configure two websites on Xampp / Lampp Server i.e. wordpress site using 80/443 Ports name myabcweb.com and Java Spring Website using 8080 / 8443 ports names myabcjavaweb.com.
I think this can be done using url rewriting  or apache vhosts.
How can i achieve it please help me.